# Is it in 2NF or not?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-normalization

R1(A, B, C, D) is a relation. It is specified that every attribute has only atomic values, and there is a set of dependencies (BD->C, C->A). It's clear to me that the relation is in the 1NF, but is it in the 2NF? I mean, BD is obviously a primary key, and we can conclude that BD->A, so all the attributes depend on the key. It isn't in the 3NF, for sure, because the 3NF doesn't accept transitive dependencies, but this shouldn't be a problem for the 2NF. I'm having doubts because some people told me that this couldn't be in 2NF. Is my reasoning correct? Is it in 2NF or not?

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a forum to share opinions about topics. Please check [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Quote the definitions you are using for 2NF etc & show use of them. (Also you don't seem to realize that not in 3NF implies not in 2NF, or that PKs are irrelevant, and your "we can conclude" is unsound & backwards, so you seem to need to revisit multiple definitions, axioms & theorems and how to apply them.) Per your original final question "Opinions?", that is not a valid SO question; per your (originally title) question is it in 2NF, that is too broad, and per your (originally implicit) question of whether your reasoning is correct, no, since it doesn't apply definitions/theorems.

Answer (score 1):

A relation schema is in 2NF if any non-prime (i.e. not belonging to a candidate key) attribute is fully functionally dependent on a candidate key.

This definition implies that, if a dependency X → A can be derived in which A is not a prime attribute and X is a proper subset of a candidate key, then such dependency violates the 2NF.

Since the (only) candidate key of this relation is BD, the attributes A and C are non-primes.

Since BD → C, is given, and BD → A can be derived, while neither B → A or D → A can be derived, then the relation is in 2NF.

Note that the 2NF has only historical interest, and the normalization process is discussed in many books (and formal algorithms are presented) only for BCNF, 3NF and higher normal forms.

Comment: I know it only has historical interest, but this was a part of a multiple-answer quiz where the answers were a)1NF b)2NF c)3NF d)BCNF. As I stated above, I was sure it is not in the 3NF, so the point of debate was -> it is in 2NF or just in the 1NF? It seems that I was right, thank you!

Comment: @CalinZapan You are not "right" in your question because your reasoning is unsound, you are not following the definitions, axioms & theorems, which this answer does.